# Google CloudVision API BatchAnnotateImagesResponse web based images details

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, batch-processing, google-cloud-vision

How could one know in what exact web based image the text was detected when multiple web based images are sent to the cloud vision api in a single request using BatchAnnotateImagesRequest? BatchAnnotateImagesResponse doesn't return that information which is kinda odd... It has ImageAnnotationContext, which holds image details, but it's reserved only for files and not web based images.

Is there some way to do this? Maybe like preserving order of images in request / response or something down that line.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: hey, sure, thanks, I didn't know that ML is reserved for "Meta Language"...

Answer (score 2):

Solved it with some help from Google Cloud Community. Essentially BatchAnnotateImageResponse keeps same order as BatchAnnotateImageRequest which can be used for our purposes to pair images with their respective CloudVision responses. It's not optimal solution, but it does the job at this moment.